# Txt ajax file shows up in network tab, but isint displaying the text

Tags: node.js, ajax

//server.js

This is my node.js server. Im trying to understand node and its base functionality before i head into express. also backend in general is confusing to me.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if(req.url === '/'){ 
        fs.readFile('home.html', function(err, data) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
});

server.listen(3000);

console.log("listening on 3000");
```

//home.html

basic html file. It contains a button. and on pressing the button i intend for the sample.txt file to be printed. I press the button and the sample.txt successfully goes into the network tab. but for some reason will not display the contents into the console window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Little structure
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="demo">
            <h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
            <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
            </div>

        <script>
            function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.open("GET", "sample.txt", true);
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };

  xhttp.send();
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

//sample.txt

HELLO FROM SAMPLE.TEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add router to server side , as below and client side will receive the message :

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if(req.url === '/'){ 
        fs.readFile('home.html', function(err, data) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }

    //add router to here
    if(req.url === '/sample.txt'){

        fs.readFile('./sample.txt', function(err, data) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        })

    }

});
```

you can read more router from express.js for advance